# Rsync with windows accounts?

Tags: windows, backup, authentication, rsync

I am trying to rsync between two windows computers, without using ssh.

IS there anything special I should do or will rsync be able to make use of windows accounts the same as unix accounts? Or do I need to do something special when it comes to authentication?

Comment: Which rsync do you have installed on the Windows machines?

Comment: So I should guess by the answers that rsync can't make use of windows credentials? @John, cwrsync

Comment: Rsync will absolutely use the credentials of the OS that it's on. It doesn't implement its own authentication scheme. Some server software, like FreeSHHd, will allow you to use OS accounts or set up additional accounts strictly within what it serves - but that's doubly-irrelevant to your question, since you say you're not doing this over SSH. Have you tried and run into problems, or are you just asking before you get started testing?

Comment: I was just curious before I started testing, but one of the answers below actually serves my purpose, and I don't need to use an account after all. Thanks.

Comment: OK - don't forget to actually accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't one of these answers that worked for me...using two colons and contacting the rsync daemon was the best solution, and I found that listed in another questions. Should I still accept an answer anyway?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to rsync, and using the SMB/CIFS mounting trick suggested by garconcn, you can also use [Unison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison_(file_synchronizer)). It's multi-platform, and there should be a native binary for Windows so you don't have to use Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

1. Map first Windows drive to second Windows, so the drive on second windows is "Y" driver.
2. Use rsync on second windows computer to copy data between those two computers.

rsync -vrtz /cygdrive/d/data /cygdrive/y/

You need to install Cygwin from http://cygwin.com and the necessary packages such like: "Rsync", "cygrunsrv", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Checking my own installation of cwrsync doesn't help but I also have FreeSSHd installed on the same server. That one will allow you to use Windows accounts, so if you can set up rsync to use SSH through the latter you just might be on a winner. I haven't tried it myself and I'm no rsync or SSH expert, so you're on your own from here.